# Nested iframe in vue2 app has no click events

Tags: laravel, iframe, vuejs2, vuejs3

My company has a large legacy project, with a laravel backend and different frontend applications.
I am working on a new frontend application (vue3), that should be nested in an existing vue2 application with an iframe.
The new App is served on the same origin and the can be called by:

1. Its route (my-local-host/apps/my-new-vue3-app)
2. Or in the old vue2 app by the iframe

**Problem:**

If open the new app on its specific route everything works fine
But if a open the app with the iframe, every click event is removed from the iframes DOM.

1. I thought it might just be the z-index, but thats not the case.
2. I implemented an iframe in another frontend projects of ours (ember.js) and everything works fine.

It seems that vue2 wrapper app might be the problem. I also think that, because a colleague of mine told me that they had the same problem before, but unfortunately the person that solved this problem is no longer in my company.

NOTE: it is interesting though, that css hover effects or inputs are working as intended.

Comment: Please check existing of <iframe sandbox="value"> attribute. If sandbox is added, simply remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no sandbox attribute.